# Pullback of tangent bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry

Hello everybody please help me with this doubt.
Let $$f:\mathbb{P^1} \rightarrow X$$ where $X$ is a projective non singular variety of dimension $n$. How could I compute the pullback $f^*T_X$? I know that by Grothendieck-Birchoff $$f^*T_X =\sum_{i=1}^nO(a_i)$$ but my problem here is try to find these $a_i$. Please help me - for example, in the case when $X=\mathbb{P}^2$ or $X=\mathbb{K}^3$ or maybe on another easy variety. I want to learn the technique with an example. Thank you.

Remark:
$f$ is a rational curve  i.e $f(\mathbb{P^1})$ birational with $\mathbb{P^1}$

Comment: When $f$ is an embedding, denote $C=f(\mathbb P^1)$, there is an exact sequence $0\to T_{C}\to T_X|_{C}\to N_{C|X}\to 0$. For example if $X$ is a surface, the degree of the normal bundle $N_{C|X}$ is the self-intersection $d=C\cdot C$. So you have $0\to O(2)\to T_X|_{C}\to O(d)\to 0$.

Comment: Thanks u ...one question ...why $c_{1}(f^{*}T_X)=3d$ where $d$ is degree of $f(\mathbb{P}^1)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give a partial result in the case $X=\mathbb P^2$. I will also assume that $f$ has degree *one* onto its image. (Because other maps factor through such a map.)

Recall tangent sheaf of $X=\mathbb P^2$ fits into the exact sequence

$$0\to \mathcal{O}\to \mathcal{O}(1)^{\oplus 3}\to T_X\to 0.$$

Pullback via $f^*$, then take $c_1$, denote $d=\deg f(\mathbb P^1)$, one has $$c_1(f^*T_X)=3d.\tag{1}\label{1}$$

On the other hand, there is an associated exact sequence $$0\to T_{\mathbb P^1}\to f^*T_{X}\to N_f\to 0,$$
where $N_f$ is the normal sheaf associated to the map $f:\mathbb P^1\to X$. By the fact $T_{\mathbb P^1}=\mathcal{O}(2)$ and $(\ref{1})$, the exact sequence reduces to 
$$0\to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb P^1}(2)\to f^*T_{X}\to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb P^1}(3d-2)\to 0 \tag{2}\label{2}$$

whose extension class $e$ lives in $H^1(\mathbb P^1,\mathcal{E})$ where $\mathcal{E}=Hom(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb P^1}(3d-2),\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb P^1}(2))\cong \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb P^1}(4-3d)$. Since $H^1(\mathbb P^1,O_{\mathbb P^1}(n))\neq 0$ only if $n=-2$, it follows that when $d\neq 2$, the exact sequence $(\ref{2})$ has to splits, so $$f^*T_X\cong \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb P^1}(2)\oplus\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb P^1}(3d-2).$$

When $d=2$, $f$ is an embedding and $f(\mathbb P^1)$ is a smooth conic, and it seems to me that $f^*T_X$ should be one of the following two cases: $$\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb P^1}(2)\oplus \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb P^1}(4), \text{when}\  e=0;$$

$$\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb P^1}(3)\oplus \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb P^1}(3), \text{when}\  e\neq0.$$

But I don't know which case it belongs to. Any comment is welcome!

Comment: Hi ..thank u for help me..i have some naive questions     how do u compute that $N_f=O_{\mathbb{P}^1}(3d-2)$ are u using the $c_{1}( f^*T_X)$ for compute the normal bundle of $f$.. is there a general result for normal bundles of rational curves ?.....you wrote that the degree of the normal bundle $N_{C,X}$ is the self intersection of the curve ..then i think that the self intersection of a rational curve of degree $d$ is $3d-2$ in $\mathbb(P)^2$..its true ?

Comment: the other naive question is ..what is the extension class $e$ ? i did not find this definition...well you said that $e$ lies in $H^{1}(\mathbb{P}^{1},\varepsilon)$ then i think that if $H^{1}(\mathbb{P}^{1},\varepsilon)$ is not zero then the short exact sequence $(2)$ will became on splits( ie: there is a section) and $f^{*}T_X$ is equal to $O(2) \oplus O_{\mathbb{P}^1}(3d-4)$ its true or i am wrong ?

Comment: the last naive question is ...why if $d=2$  then $f(\mathbb{P}^1)$ is a smooth conic ? i know that if degree is 2 then it is a conic but why also is smooth ?and i dont get understand the claim  $O_{\mathbb{P}^1}(2) \oplus O_{\mathbb{P}^1}(4)$ when $e=0$ why ?..if $d=2$ then $H^{1}(\mathbb{P}^{1},\varepsilon)=0$ then what happen with the sequence (2) is not will be split ? really ? then i dont understand how u can write in direct sum ...please help me with these doubts ..and thank u

Comment: @alberthNUÑEZSULLCA For an exact sequence $0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$ of sheaves, $c(B)=c(A)c(C)$, where $c=1+c_1+c_2+...$ is Chern polynomial. Since the base $\mathbb P^1$ has dimension one, $c=1+c_1$, and $c_1(f^*T_X)=c_1(T_{\mathbb P^1})+c_1(N_f)$.

Comment: @alberthNUÑEZSULLCA It is a general fact that for an exact sequence (of vector bundles) $0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$, the extension class $e$ lives in $Hom(C,A)$, the extension class is zero iff the s.e.s splits.

Comment: @alberthNUÑEZSULLCA A singular conic should be union of two line, it has two components, cannot be image of $\mathbb P^1$.

Comment: thank u ...but why  $c_{1}(f^{*}T_X)$=3d ? you use this fact for compute $c_{1}(N_f)$

Comment: @alberthNUÑEZSULLCA Just calculate the degree of $\mathcal{O}(1)$ restricted to $f(\mathbb P^1)$. Take a general line $L$ in $\mathbb P^2$, intersects at $d$ distinct (smooth) points on $f(\mathbb P^1)$. This means the restriction of $\mathcal{O}(1)$ to the possibly singular curve $f(\mathbb P^1)$ has degree $d$. Then use the assumption $f$ has degree one and $c_1$ is additive on direct sum.

Comment: thank u again...one last question please ..why $f^*T_X=O(3) \oplus O(3) $ when $e \neq 0 $

Comment: @alberthNUÑEZSULLCA It is an exercise that if there is a nontrivial map $O(n)\to O(m)$, then $n\le m$. Then you can show when integer $a\neq 2, 3, 4$, the quotient of $0\to O(2)\to O(a)+O(6-a)$ is not locally free. So the only possibility for nontrivial extension is $0\to O(2)\to O(3)+O(3)\to O(4)\to 0$. I don't know what are the morphisms between them, but if you have worked out, please let me know.

Comment: thanks u your help was very good..i will work on ths

Comment: Dear @AG learner ...the short exact sequence$$0 \rightarrow T_{\mathbb{P}^1} \rightarrow f^{*}T_X \rightarrow N_f \rightarrow 0 $$ exist if $f(\mathbb{P}^1) \subset X$ is smooth, but not always its happens for example if the image is the nodal curve...then did u use the fact the all morphism factor through and embedding and a finite morphism ? am i wrong ? also suppose that $$ g:\mathbb{P}^1 \rightarrow Y$$ is the embedding of the factorization of $f$ then $f^{*}T_X = g^{*}T_Y$ ? it is a consequence ? and necesarilly  $Y=X$ or it only happens when $X=\mathbb{P}^2$...please help me

Comment: @alberthNUÑEZSULLCA The exact sequence does not need to assume if $f$ is an embedding. Sorry I didn't understand the rest of your question.

Comment: dear @AG learner this sequence exist in general for $Y \subset X$ with $X$ and $Y$ non singular ..in our case $X=\mathbb{P}^2$ is non singular but $Y=f(\mathbb{P}^1)$ is not necesary not singular

Comment: @alberthNUÑEZSULLCA Harris's  Moduli of curves, page 96 is the sequence that I refer to.

Comment: dear @AG learner ..yes i am seeing ..but ther define $N_f$ as $coker(df:T_X \rightarrow f^{*}T_Y)$ then necesarilly Y and X have to be 
 both smooth because how could i define well tangent bundle ?